# Create an Update statement using a Having Count clause on sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle, count, sqlplus, having

I want to create an update query from a select statement which uses a HAVING COUNT

This is the select query:

```
select hlse_ref, HLSE_TERM_START_DATE, HLSE_STATUS_CODE
from headleas a, lernhist b
where a.hlse_ref=b.lerh_leas_hlse_ref
and a.HLSE_TERM_START_DATE is not null
group by a.hlse_ref, a.HLSE_STATUS_CODE, a.HLSE_TERM_START_DATE
having count(b.LERH_START_DATE)=1
```

And I want to set hlse_term_start_date to null where the conditions meet what is on my select statement

```
update headleas
set hlse_term_start_date=null
where( *my select statement*)
```

but this doesn't seem to work. I've looked at other posts but they weren't much help for this case. I'm using SQL Plus. Any ideas guys?

Comment: Do you have in mind, that you need to link these two queries via columns e.g. ... WHERE ID IN ( *select statement with one column* ) ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't the logic you are trying to build, but may be this can help

use an exists clause like

```
update headless outer
set hlse_term_start_date=null
where exists ( select 1 from headleas a, lernhist b
where a.hlse_ref=b.lerh_leas_hlse_ref
and a.HLSE_TERM_START_DATE is not null
and outer.hlse_ref = a.hlse_ref
group by a.hlse_ref, a.HLSE_STATUS_CODE, a.HLSE_TERM_START_DATE
having count(b.LERH_START_DATE)=1 
)
```

or

compare subquery count in where clause like

```
update headless outer
set hlse_term_start_date=null
where 1= (
select count(b.LERH_START_DATE)
from headleas a, lernhist b
where a.hlse_ref=b.lerh_leas_hlse_ref
and a.HLSE_TERM_START_DATE is not null
and a.hlse_ref = outer.hlse_ref
group by a.hlse_ref, a.HLSE_STATUS_CODE, a.HLSE_TERM_START_DATE
)
```

Comment: Thanks, your first update query works for me like a charm! All I needed was the where exists clause.

Answer (score 0):

What is your where condition supposed to be, exactly? The example you give is not the right syntax.

```
update table_b b
set b.col1 = null
where (select col2 from table_a a) --incorrect
```

This is not a where condition; it doesn't evaluate to true or false. Did you mean to use "where exists"? Or some other where condition? If you use "where exists", you have to correlate your select statement to the updated table using some key value, presumably the primary key of HEADLEAS.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I see now that I had to use where exists clasue and that's why my update query didn't work. I've already joined my PKs together, that hlse_ref and lerh_leas_hlse_ref.